# Determining the complete set of sequences${\{p_n}\}$ valid for Weierstrass factorization theorem

Tags: number-theory

If we assume that we know the following two criteria are met:

$$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty } \left| a_{{n}} \right| =\infty \tag{i}$$
$$r \gt 0\tag{ii}$$

I want to know how to determine the set:
$$\mathbb{P}= \left\{  \left\{ p_{{n}}   \right\}:\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left( {\frac {r}{ \left| a_{{n}} \right| }}
 \right) ^{1+p_{{n}}}<\infty 
  \right\}\tag{0}$$

One way to ensure that the predicate above is met would be to impose the predicate:

$$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty } \left( {\frac {r}{ \left| a_{{n}}
 \right| }} \right) ^{1+p_{{n}}}=0
\tag{1}$$

Furthermore, in order to ensure this to be true, given we only know (i)  and (ii), we need the following to be valid, since these conditions ensure the limit inside the exponent brackets to be zero:

$$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty } \left( {\frac {r}{ \left| a_{{n}}
 \right| }} \right) ^{1+p_{{n}}}= \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\left( \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }{
\frac {r}{ \left| a_{{n}} \right| }} \right) ^{1+p_{{n}}}=0
\tag{2}$$

So we know that to ensure (2) is valid ${\{p_n}\}$ must be an increasing sequence, so from that basis I thought a valid answer would be:

$$\mathbb{P}= \left\{  \left\{ p_{{n}}   \right\}:\ p_n \geq n-1
  \right\} \quad n \in \mathbb N\tag{3}$$

Comment: Your (1) does not ensure that the series converges. Take $p_n=0$ and $a_n=n$, then $\frac{r}n\to0$ but $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{r}n=\infty$. There is no explicit way to express convergence of a series in terms of its general term.

Comment: (2) prohibits $p_n=0$

Comment: that's the basis of my reasoning that ${\{p_n}\}$ must be increasing and a subset of $\mathbb Z^+$

Comment: (2) does not prohibit $p_n=0$ as written. You need two different letters for the repeated limit, and the inside limit is just 0 by (i). $p_n\sim n$ is not enough, but $p_n\sim n^{1+\epsilon}$ with $\epsilon>0$ (or growing faster) will be sufficient since then because then $\left( \frac {r}{| a_n|}\right)^{1+p_n}\sim \frac1{n^{1+\epsilon}}$.

Comment: Thanks  I'll accept that as an answer if you want to cut and paste the comment